# Nmap scans are not persistent after reboot

Tags: kali-linux, port, nmap

I use Zenmap on Linux 6.0.0-kali3-amd64 which runs on Oracle VirtualBox to see open ports in Metasploitable2. When I save the Zenmap scan to `/home` I can successfully open the scan again until I reboot my device. Although other settings and files persist the Zenmap scan is gone.

Here is my command on Zenmap with the profile set to Intense scan:

```
nmap -T4 -A -v 172.16.xxx.xx
```

Can someone help me to save my scans, so they are persistent?

Edit: Since I use Zenmap GUI to run the scans, I save the scans by: Going to Scan (in the toolbar) -> Save Scan -> Choose the directory -> Save

Comment: Welcome to U&L.  What's the exact command you use to save the scan? Please don't answer in comments, rather [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/740353/edit) the question to add new info / clarifications / etc.

Comment: You are using a live system without persistence, right?

Comment: Thanks! @Peregrino69. I addressed your concern. Tell me if there are any errors in the way I did it.

Comment: @Panki If I had been using it without persistence, then the other files that I save also should not be available when I start my system again.